Is this a known special function? (Some relative of the first kind modified Bessel)
I struggle with identifying the following expression
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp\left( t \cos \theta + t \cos \left( \alpha \theta \right) + t \cos (\beta \theta) \right) \, d \theta
$$
as a function of $t$. If $\alpha = \beta = 0$, this is a modified Bessel function of first kind
$$
I_0(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{t \cos \theta} d \theta.
$$
However, I cannot find any way to reexpress this object for other real $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I am particularly interested in the case when $\alpha + \beta = 1$.

Are $\alpha, \beta$ integers?  If not, then $\cos(\alpha \theta)$ and $\cos(\beta\theta)$ do not have period $2\pi$, so the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ does not do well with that integrand.

Where does the integral come from?

@GEdgar, in the particular place where I've encountered this, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are rational and they add up to $1$.

@ТymaGaidash, I found this as a certain moment generating function.
